# Find a temperature and work out how long it remained >= this temperature

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet with times in one column and temperatures in another. I'm trying to work out a formula that will find a certain temperature and measure how long it remained at that temperature.

```
11:25:29 AM 69.3°C
11:26:29 AM 69.6°C
11:27:29 AM 69.8°C
11:28:29 AM 70.0°C
11:29:29 AM 70.2°C
11:35:29 AM 70.8°C
11:36:29 AM 70.3°C
11:37:29 AM 69.5°C
11:38:29 AM 68.5°C
11:39:29 AM 67.5°C
12:39:29 PM 66.3°C
1:39:29 PM  52.1°C
2:39:29 PM  12.1°C
3:39:29 PM  5.0°C
```

In this example, I would like to find when it hit 70.0°C and how long it stayed above 70.0°C.

Comment: If you input `69.9°C` would you want the starting datetime to be `11:27:29 AM` or `11:28:29 AM` or split between the times for `69.8°C` and `70.0°C` proportionately (e.g. `11:27:59 AM`) ?

Comment: The temperatures are recorded by a temp logger every minute. I cut some recordings out just to show for example.

Comment: That's nice to know. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Did you ever figure out an answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a tough problem because you might have multiple occasions where you go above 70 degrees. In that case, do you want the total time spent above 70 in the entire dataset, or do you want the total time spent above 70 consecutively? And then, how are you determining which of these potential multiple nonconsecutive periods you are talking about?

That said, you can try this. If column A is your datetime, and column B is your temp reading, specify another cell as your temperature reference value ($D$1 here), and in column C starting in row 2 do this:

```
=(A2-A1)*IF(B2>=$D$1,1,0)
```

and then copy that all the way down. What that does is it calculates the time difference between measurements and then if the temperature at that time is greater than your reference, it multiplies it by 1, otherwise it multiplies by 0. Because a date/time in Excel is really just a number, what you get is an interval of a day between measurements in each cell of column C. In other words, .25 = 6 hours.

Now that you have that data in column C, you are free to further parse it. You can use a simple `SUM(C:C)` formula in a cell, or you can go back and sum up individual ranges. I hope this helps.